# Visual Studio Detached Branch Rebase in Progress issue

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I have seen a few of these posts around but all involve running git commands. So since I do not run git commands I apologize if this is simpler than I think.
We are using Microsoft visual studio team foundation service

I have an issue with a branch that I merged inside visual studio. I am running VS 2019.

1. I cannot switch from the Detached branch as you can see this image here: [image: Visual Studio Branch View]
2. I cannot do anything to move the branch forward. Everything is grayed out: [image: Grayed out Options for Git]
3. I cannot use master branch to create a new branch and switch to it.

Initially I had a warning in git: :"unable to pull because your local and remote branches changed. set your preferred git behavior for how to reconcile diverged branches in git settings."

So I ended up going to Toolbar | Git | Settings
I changed the following setting: [image: Rebase setting changed]

Please help! Thanks!

Here is my git status response... Please let me know how to proceed :(
[image: Git status response]

Comment: When a rebase is in progress, Visual Studio usually offers "Continue" and "Abort" buttons, but if you don't see them (which I recall happening sometimes), you can just do it from the command line: `git rebase --continue` or `git rebase --abort`.

Comment: Regarding your wish to avoid using the command line, depending on the motivations behind that, perhaps you could start with an innocuous command such as `git status`. It's a command that doesn't change state and only prints information. Displaying the output here may help others help you.

Comment: Yikes! Ok I did not have git installed. Got it installed looks like we are moving now using the command line! I will post back if I continue to have issues!

Comment: Update git status response above! Thanks!

Comment: This line from the status helps: "You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on 'a104370'." I'm guessing that was unintentional? Since the time you began the rebase (which I think was you attempting to `pull` with the `--rebase` flag turned on), if you haven't done any work that you care about keeping, you can abort the rebase to get back to where you started before the `pull`. The command to abort is `git rebase --abort`. cont...

Comment: If you did stuff during the rebase that you don't want to lose, stage everything you have pending right now, commit it with a message like "wip: just in case", and then abort the rebase. You'll be able to get any changes back you made during the rebase by using `git reflog` to find your "wip" commmit.

Comment: I actually did try to abort. I get this long error essentially: error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by reset:
        lib/RCAJAX/2022.2.511.45.Trial/AdditionalLibraries/Bin45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll... and finally at the end this is the error: Aborting
fatal: could not move back to 8342857cda1be925f5ff44f22c54a86048e7590f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up bailing on the whole rebase. I simply cut the folder and put it in a different location. Then I pulled back in the code from my team foundation service.

then I merged in the differences by just pulling in the files I knew I updated. Very annoying but I could not figure it out otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies, but on a rebase operation with conflicts, you have to make sure that all the files are **staged** before continuing. This includes the files updated while merging.

Answer (score 0):

When you checkout from a commit instead of a branch you "time travel", Git moves your HEAD to that commit's SHA (commit hash). From that point in time to the next commits, all code is lost, that is why you get the message "Detached" is not longer linear.